# Entry widget doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm fairly new to python and I need help with this problem. How do I get a user to input something on canvas? I've tried taking out the `x=` and `y=` but it doesn't work... after I run the module it says "Non-Keyword arg after Keyword arg". Please help.

```
from tkinter import*   
def main():     
   global window     
   global tkinter     
   global canvas     
   window = Tk()     
   canvas = Canvas(window, width=400, height=300, bg='blue')    
   e1 = Entry(canvas)     
   canvas.create_window(window=e1, x=100,y=100)      
   e1.pack()      
   canvas.pack()     
   window.mainloop() 
main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of the created window has to be passed as the first two arguments, not as keyword arguments.

```
canvas.create_window(100, 100, window=e1)
```

Also, the `Entry` widget doesn't need to be packed when used in this manner, so the `e1.pack()` line should be removed entirely.

Comment: oh thank god thank you soooooooo much Tigerhawk thank you soooo much

Comment: Hey i dont suppose you'd know how to resize the text box entry? if possible that is thanks heaps works now.

Comment: You can choose the width in characters with the `width` keyword, e.g. `e1 = Entry(canvas, width=10)`. If you want more than one line and more options, you'll have to go with a `Text` widget instead of `Entry`.

Comment: thank you so much TigerHawk you the best also sorry to bother again dont suppose youd know how to resize the text?

Comment: With the `font` keyword, e.g. `e1 = Entry(canvas, width=10, font='Helvetica 20')`.

Comment: thank you soooo much TigerHawk works thank you sooooo much this is better than google :-)

Comment: TigerHawk your my only hope i need your help

Comment: I'm trying to make a little program where it helps someone improve on their basic addition and subtraction, so i need help on the part where its bout the userinput == answer and displays correct but its just not working how do i post my program it to long?

Comment: Try to troubleshoot it yourself first. Use any error messages it produces to track down the source of problems. If you can't figure it out on your own (with research), edit your code down to the smallest program that still demonstrates the problem (the code in this question is a good example) and ask a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your help ill re ask the question and include my program thank you so much for your help.